# Rails LIKE query for search was working but no longer is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Ruby on Rails project I created. It uses Rails for the backend and the frontend.

Months ago I had it so that you could search for hikes by searching a keyword that was in the hike name. The hikes matching the search would then show up on the screen.

However, I recently noticed this isn't working anymore. There isn't really an error showing anywhere though.

However, I've done some digging and noticed with binding.pry that the LIKE query I had in my Hike model is no longer working.

I feel that the method in my Hike model should work as coded like this:

```
def self.search_by_name(search)
  if search
     Hike.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

From my prying I've noticed that this method is being hit and search is coming through as an argument correctly. However, doing `Hike.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")` in binding.pry returns an empty array, as shown (not sure if the second line showing `"hikes".*` is what it should be showing or not):

```
pry(Hike)> Hike.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  Hike Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "hikes".* FROM "hikes" WHERE (name LIKE '%park%')
  ↳ app/models/hike.rb:18:in `search_by_name'
=> []
```

I recently switched my db from SQLite to PostgreSQL so perhaps that change is requiring a different syntax to be used in my querying within that above method?

Below is how my HikesController looks, where you can see that if params[:q], which means that if someone typed in a search, I am setting `@hikes` equal to the calling of the `.search_by_name` method being passed the search term. The `.search_by_name` method, as shown above, is returning an empty array when you've searched a word, and I've been searching words that are in specific hike names in my database.

```
class HikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login

      def index
        if params[:hike] && params[:hike][:":location"] != "None"
          @hikes = Hike.search(params[:hike][:":location"])
        elsif params[:q]
          @hikes = Hike.search_by_name(params[:q])
        else
          @hikes = Hike.all
        end
      end
    
      def require_login
        return head(:forbidden) unless session.include? :user_id
      end
    end
```

As a reminder, this search functionality was working before. Not sure why it isn't now, but I'm curious if it has something to do with changes that are possibly needed after switching my db from SQLite to PostgreSQL. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I should note that after migrating from SQLite to PostgreSQL my database does seem to be populated correctly. Doing `Hike.all` in the rails console does still give me all of my seeded hikes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQLite, [`like` is case-insensitive by default](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like). `%park%` will match `Park`.

In Postgres it is case-sensitive. To make it case-insensitive use `ilike`.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working again using `ilike`.